# pip uninstall to clean up generated files

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

How to get pip to clean up better?

I have a pip module that does two things I would like un-done:

a) remove a dependent module dynamically specified during install - think sister binary package with os and python version in name. Those are now obsolete since I've learned the manylinux (and soon the universal) wheel dance.

b) remove license, usage, and telemetry files created while running the module.

Is there a hook or something that I can add a bit of logic and fileio too?

Seems option a was designed for but never implemented with the *obsoletes* keyword found at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.htm